# Create a Magick++ Image from an RGBQUAD pointer

Tags: c++, imagemagick

I need to convert an `RGBQUAD` pointer to a `Magic::Image`. I tried with the code below. However, it crashes with `Magick::ErrorCorruptImage`

```
Blob blob = Blob(pBuffer, width*height*sizeof(RGBQUAD));
Image img;
img.size(Geometry(width, height));
img.magick("RGBA");
img.read(blob);
```

So how can I convert the RGBQUAD array to a Magick::Image?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the error is caused by "RGBA" format defaulting to `Quantum` size. Usually `16Q`.

Just set the `Magick::Image.depth` to `8Q` as [`RGBQUAD`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162938(v=vs.85).aspx) should be `BYTE` data types.

```c++
Blob blob = Blob(pBuffer, width*height*sizeof(RGBQUAD));
Image img;
img.size(Geometry(width, height));
img.depth(8);
img.magick("RGBA");
img.read(blob);
```

... *But* ...
In `RGBQUAD` the last byte is reserved, and not an alpha channel. Quote from docs...

> **rgbReserved**
>
> This member is reserved and must be zero.

This would make any blob you pass to ImageMagick transparent.

I would suggest coping the data to a new buffer, and ensuring that the last byte is fully opaque.

For example...

```c++
// Note: I'm using data type `uint8_t' over `BYTE' for no particular reason.
size_t rgbquad_size = sizeof(RGBQUAD);
size_t total_bytes = width * height * rgbquad_size;
uint8_t * pCopyBuffer = new uint8_t[total_bytes];
for (size_t cursor = 0; cursor < total_bytes; ++cursor) {
    if (cursor % rgbquad_size < rgbquad_size - 1) {
        pCopyBuffer[cursor] = pBuffer[cursor];
    } else {
        pCopyBuffer[cursor] = 0xFF;
    }
}
Blob blob = Blob(pCopyBuffer, total_bytes);
```

**Edit from comments**

If `pBuffer` is defined as `RGBQUAD *`, than it would be easier to iterate over them, and assign the alpha channel value.

```c++
for (size_t cursor = 0; cursor < width*height; ++cursor)
    pBuffer[cursor].rgbReserved = 0xFF; // Set Alpha
```

Comment: Visual Studio says it cannot convert from RGBQUAD to uint8_t. Any idea on how to fix that?

Comment: How is `pBuffer` defined?

Comment: As `RGBQUAD* pBuffer`.

Comment: I also tried using your method without a buffer (despite the alpha channel not working) and it crashed with the same error.

Comment: How was the `pBuffer` data allocated?

Comment: The pBuffer data is pulled from a KinectV2. I can write the pBuffer to a Bitmap just fine.

Comment: The `Magick::ErrorCorruptImage` is coming from `pBuffer` not having enough data to satisfy `width*height*sizeof(RGBQUAD)`. I can only suggest  putting in a few break points and ensuring that the buffer was allocated with enough memory, and that the data was copied fully.

Comment: Well I have set Breakpoints and ensured there is enough data. (For example: `pBuffer[width*height]` has RGB values.) And as I said, I can write the `pBuffer` to a bmp file without a problem. Maybe `width*height*sizeof(RGBQUAD)` does not calculate the right amount of bytes for a `Magick::Image`?